# How to disconnect/stop scanning of Socket Mobile scanner using API?

Tags: ios, swift, socketscan

In my app Socket Mobile Scanner is integrated to scan inventory items, my requirement is to stop scanner's scanning until the app search/check items existence.

If the recent items is not valid item, Scanner should stop scanning.

I used below code :

```
/// here scanApiHelper is instance of ScanApiHelper 
scanApiHelper?.pop(self)
scanApiHelper?.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a data confirmation mode that you can use which will cover this scenario. In this mode, the trigger is lock for a certain time unless you explicitly acknowledge the data from the app. The trigger lockout time can be configured. The other possibility is to disable the trigger temporally and re-enable it when your app is ready.

Have a look at the github singleentry-ios (https://github.com/SocketMobile/singleentryswift-ios) it has a code example of Data Confirmation :

```
    func onDecodedDataResult(_ result: Int, device: DeviceInfo!, decodedData: ISktScanDecodedData!) {
    print("onDecodedDataResult in the detail view")
    if result==ESKT_NOERROR {
        let rawData = decodedData.getData()
        let rawDataSize = decodedData.getSize()
        let data = Data(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(rawData!), count: Int(rawDataSize))
        print("Size: \(rawDataSize)")
        print("data: \(data)")
        let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        let string = str as! String
        print("Decoded Data \(string)")
        self.decodedData.text = string
        // this code can be removed if the application is not interested by
        // the host Acknowledgment for the decoded data
        #if HOST_ACKNOWLEDGMENT
            ScanApiHelper.shared().postSetDataConfirmationOkDevice(device, target: self, response: #selector(onSetDataConfirmation(_:)))
        #endif
    }
}

#if HOST_ACKNOWLEDGMENT
func onSetDataConfirmation(_ scanObj: ISktScanObject){
    let result = scanObj.msg().result()
    if result != ESKT_NOERROR {
        print("error trying to confirm the decoded data: \(result)")
    }
}
#endif
```

The scanner needs to be configured once to this mode:

```
    #if HOST_ACKNOWLEDGMENT
        scanApiHelper?.postGetLocalAcknowledgmentDevice(deviceInfo, target: self, response: #selector(onGetLocalAcknowledgment(_:)))
        scanApiHelper?.postGetDecodeActionDevice(deviceInfo, target: self, response: #selector(onGetDecodeAction(_:)))
    #else // to remove the Host Acknowledgment if it was set before
        scanApiHelper?.postGetLocalAcknowledgmentDevice(deviceInfo, target: self, response: #selector(onGetLocalAcknowledgmentLocalAck(_:)))
        scanApiHelper?.postGetDecodeActionDevice(deviceInfo, target: self, response: #selector(onGetDecodeActionLocalAck(_:)))
    #endif
```

I hope this helps.